# Selenium getText not working and HTML not have any attribute containing text

Tags: html, selenium

Trying to capture text of `WebElement` with below two methods but both returning blank string

```
// Method 1 

 d.findElement(By.id("deliveryDate")).getTex();

// Method 2

 WebElement deliveryDate = d.findElement(By.id("deliveryDate"));

 System.out.println( (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerText;", deliveryDate));
```

Want to capture "THU 2 FEB 17"

SS >> [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXHPU.png)

```html
<label class="fieldset" _ngcontent-nok-32="">
<span class="caption captionPrimary" _ngcontent-nok-32="">Expiry</span>
<tp-datepicker _ngcontent-nok-32="" _nghost-nok-35="">
<input id="expiryDate" class="highlighted ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" type="text" _ngcontent-nok-32="" formcontrolname="expiryDate" required="" spellcheck="false" tabindex="103"/>
<button _ngcontent-nok-35="" tabindex="-1"/>
</tp-datepicker>
<span class="tenorWrap" _ngcontent-nok-32="">
<!--template bindings={}-->
<span class="tenor" _ngcontent-nok-32="">                 1M               </span>
</span>
</label>
```

Comment: This is an `input` element, you should be using `deliveryDate.getAttribute("value");`

Comment: your markup does not contain any element whose id is "deliveryDate", it is "expiryDate"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WebElement expiryDate= d.findElement(By.id("expiryDate"));
string text=expiryDate.getAttribute("value");
```